# Architect of interior WebService (vs EJB App) to be consumed only by Java clients

Tags: web-services, architecture, soa

I've two locations, Location `A` in USA and Location `B` in Egypt.

**I am deploying a Web App on location `B` that need to get Data from a DB on location `A`.**

I need to create some app to be deployed on `A` to provide the web app on `B` with the data.
(I know Web App on `B` could connect to DB on `A` directly but some limitation prevent me from that)

For the App on `A`, Should I create:

1. **JSON** WebService?
2. WebService return **serialized** objects to Web app to be deserialized and used?
3. An EJB app that can be accessed **remotely via JNDI** from the webapp?

I Know JSON is a lightwieght, but is it faster or the serialization (option 2)? or should I let the app server do that for me (option 3) ?

Thanks.

Comment: I'v try nothing, I need your opinions before goging on

Answer (score 0):

Among the choices (JSON, WS, EJB)

JSON is something that client can interpret, Target application can directly consume the DB data (json) without further processing - Best approach

WS approach also seems fine but little bit complex to process directly at client side ( depends on the data interchanged) - Acceptable approach

EJB approach is complex one as your APP B needs to collect the data from APP A and process and (possibly convert) and propagate to the front end.

Comment: In case of #2, I mean a webservice that do: `obj.serialize()` and send the bytes to the client that will receive the bytes and do: `obj.deserialize()` as the two sites grantee to use Java. Is it will be faster than JSON?

Comment: usually web-services dont communicate through java, they communicated through XML/JSON based on the service implementation is choosen.

Comment: probably by obj.serialize() / obj.deserialize() approach you mean RMI ??

Comment: No, it is simply and literally as I said, The WS just serialize the object into array of bytes, send it to the client (which already have the `dto` or `stub` or whatever we name it). The client receives the Array of bytes, and deserialize it into the `dto` or `stub` it already have

Comment: do you need the data to your front end / middle tier ? if its the middle tier then WS -> ser/de-ser is the only choice. If your data can be consumed directly by your front end then, you can expose your service which serves the JSON data and from your Frontend you can have a Async call (AJAX) and interpret the JSON response using JS (or jQuery) and consume directly on the page itself